# How to configure babel in non-nodejs Environment/without npm?

Tags: babeljs, babel-loader

How to configure babel in non-nodejs Environment/without npm ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`babel-standalone`](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone). Its documentation emphasize *non-Node.js* environments just like you do:

> babel-standalone is a standalone build of Babel for use in non-Node.js environments, including browsers.

To confogure it, you can use `data-presets` and `data-plugins` attributes as also depicted in the Github page usage docs as follows:

```
<script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2015,stage-2">
```

Comment: How can i set the input path & output path of the folders for babel-standalone